# Outlook Interop: how to iterate all the calendars?

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, vsto

I want to get all events from all calendars, how do i iterate thru all calendar folders and then all events for each calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, though I'm just getting in to Outlook myself, I would suggest the following:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
```

Then something along the lines of

```
foreach (outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder in folder.Folders)
{
    // do something with subFolder
}
```

And you could probably create something recursive to exhaust all possibilities of the `MAPIFolder.Folders` property.

**EDIT** Ultimately, try stepping through in the debugger one you've gotten the default folder and see what you're left with. My guess is this will have the information you need.

Comment: I put [code]Console.WriteLine(subFolder.Name);[/code] inside the foreach and got the name of my additional calendars outputted TWICE... strange. It did not output the default calendar, are the subs children of the default?

Comment: I wish I knew. I'm still trying to understand the hierarchy of how outlook manages everything. Closest I've found to an answer is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268893%28VS.80%29.aspx but even then I've found trial-and-error to be more successful than MSDN (so what else is new). Best thing I can suggest is persistence, but if you do find an answer please post it. I'd be curious what method(s) you take to get there, may help out others in our situation trying to learn outlook's design model.